# Unique foreign key association in intermediate table

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm a bit new with Mysql and have a problem with unique constraints :p

Here are the tables :

[image]

The relation is going to be a intermediate table and the fields are going to be :

ID (primary)
userAsker (foreign key)
userAsked (foreign key)
((( accept (int) don't care)))

What I would like is that we can't have 2 times an entity whith the same 2 foreign keys like that :

ID : 1
userAsker :1
userAsked : 2

ID : 2
userAsker :1
userAsked : 2

Otherwise the user could be able to do loads of demands ... I know how to do an Index unique in phpmyadmin but I don't know how to group two fields in a unique index ... Could someone help me :S ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just execute this SQL statement in your phpmyadmin.

`alter table [your_intermedia_table_name] add unique key(userAsker, userAsked)`

Comment: Yes, the explanation is that this creates a unique index across multiple columns.

Comment: We can also select the 2 fields and click on unique in phpmyadmin :-) ;-) Thanks !